# Should in the past

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, should

If I say "I should have done it." it means that I didn't do it.

Imagine: there was something that needed to be done. And I did it. How do I say "should" about REAL past?

I should do it and I did it.

or

I should have done it and I did it. (I guess this sentence is wrong)

p.s. I guess that I can use different words such as: "I had to do it." But I want to know about "should".
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*I should do it* indicates that you **have not** done it.

So *I should do it and I did it* is semantically like saying *I haven’t done it and I did it*. It does not make sense.

*I should have done it* indicates that you **did not** do it.

So *I should have done it and I did it* is semantically like saying *I did not do it and I did it*. It does not make sense.

You need a verb that can inflect, like a “semi-modal” (*I had to do it and I did it*) or a non-modal (*I needed to do it and I did it*).

See also:

> **should**
> **3.** modal verb
>   If you say that something **should have** happened, you mean that it did not happen, but that you wish it had.
> If you say that something **should not have** happened, you mean that it
> did happen, but that you wish it had not.
>  <sub>Source: [*Collins*
> —
> should](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/should)</sub>

Comment: I knew I should quit, but I didn't. I knew I should quit, and I did.